# Using a feature as a target denominator

Tags: modeling, feature-selection, boosting, predictor, dependent-variable

Could you please tell me what (bad) can happen if I use the same feature as the denominator in the target feature and as the predictor in a boosting regression? I think I should exclude it from the predictor part, but I don't know where this feeling comes from. I appreciate any thoughts, I feel stuck. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need it in the denominator of your target feature? You can just predict the numerator and divide by this feature after the prediction of the numerator

Comment: The thing is I'm highly likely not allowed to change target and I have data as is. So I try to manipulate my features somehow. I understand your point and would rather do it your way (and I'll try, thank you). But the only option I have now is to include/exclude the feature, but I have to justify it either this or that way. So I'm trying to find any proof that it's safe (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be to predict only the numerator and divide by this target feature in the end. 
However, if your only decision (as you wrote in the comments) is to include or exclude this feature, I don't see a reason to exclude it, but only if this feature is fully accessible on serving time.
The main risk to include labels in the features, is data snooping, i.e. you "cheat" on training time, getting good performance, but then fail on serving because not all the features is fully accessible during serving.

Another advantage to go with the cleaner approach, is that sometimes it is harder (not impossible though) for some models, e.g. neural networks, to model multiplication or division. For example, in NN, the output is a composition of non linear function over linear combination of the features and the weights. Getting a direct $x_1 * x_2$ is not possible and harder to model.